# DocumentSnapshot is always null for a valid document reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm storing structured data on Firestore and I want to get the data of a specific nested document and it must be in real time because the data is updating in real time.

Here is the structure in Firestore:

[image]

So basically, I have the following path :

```
collection(Users).document(23).collection(orders).document(16)
or
/Users/23/orders/21
```

..and I want to get the data of document 16 of the "orders" collection.

---

**Here's the code**

```
  class FireStoreMapActivity{
  DocumentReference  doc;


    void getData(){

    doc = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection("Users")
                    .document(23 + "")
                    .collection("orders")
                    .document(21 + "");

     doc.addSnapshotListener(this, (documentSnapshot, e) -> {

                if (documentSnapshot != null) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        List<String> images = (List<String>) documentSnapshot.get("images");
                        Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>> size => ", locHistory.size() + " ");

                    } else {
                        Log.e(">>>>>>>> error ", " documentSnapshot != exists");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(">>>>>>>> error ", " documentSnapshot = null");
                }
            });
  }
}
```

---

But every time, the null log appear 
`Log.e(">>>>>>>> error ", " documentSnapshot = null");`

### **UPDATE**

well, after printing the exception it seems to be a permission error!

`com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Here's my ruleset

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**but how to inform Firestore that I'm in fact an authenticated user.!?**

Comment: If `documentSnapshot` is`null` and you're sure the document exists, then `e` will have a value. Print it to see what the problem is (typically it will be something about permissions).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you're right, it's a permission issue! please see the update!

Comment: It seems you're not signed in, or at least not signed in when you try to read from Firestore. Given that the code you shared shows nothing about authentication, it's hard to say more. If you'd like to verify though, log the current user just before you call `addSnapshotListener` with something like `Log.i("User", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser())`

Comment: man, you're right again, I did what you said and it shows as `null`, so I made sure I'm signed in before getting any data and it worked like charm. thanks a lot, please post the tips you mention in an answer so that I mark it as accepted and other people consider it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `documentSnapshot` is `null` and you're sure the document exists, then `e` will have a value. Print it to see what the problem is, which typically will be something about permissions.

---

From your update it seems your rules requires just an authenticated user, but your listener is rejected by the server based on those rules. This means you're not signed in, or at least not signed in when you try to read from Firestore.

Given that the code you shared shows nothing about authentication, it's hard to say more. If you'd like to verify though, log the current user just before you call `addSnapshotListener` with something like `Log.i("User", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser())`.